# Pandas. How to delete a row if value include some letters

Tags: pandas, parsing

I want to del row if value include some letters: "ing" or "ed".

Original Dataframe

```
d0 = [{'word':'del', 'count':22}, {'word':'delete', 'count':11},{'word':'deleted', 'count':2},{'word':'deleting', 'count':5}]
df0 = pd.DataFrame(d0)
```

Desirable DataFrame

```
d1 = [{'word':'del', 'count':22}, {'word':'delete', 'count':11}]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(d1)
```

I suppose that can to add column with value include last 3 letter, and next delete row if value == 'ing' or 'ed'. But I don't know how do it and it is not perfect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `str.contains` with `regex` pattern to create `boolean mask` which can be then used to filter the required rows:

```
df0[~df0['word'].str.contains(r'(?i)(?:ing|ed)$')]
```

---

```
     word  count
0     del     22
1  delete     11
```

Comment: It is will be work only at the end of the word? Otherwise the extra words will be deleted

Comment: Yes this will only search for the occurrence of `ing|ed` at the end of string. If you want to search the entire string you can remove `$`  from the regex pattern

Comment: Maybe you tell me please how delete plural form of a words, for example, 'test' and 'tests' or 'company' and 'companies'

Comment: @Alpha2020 Not sure i understand, Can you please elaborate with some sample and expected output, or better please ask a separate question?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65644796/pandas-how-to-delete-a-row-if-value-include-plural-form-of-the-words